# Responsive offset with Chrome Console "toggle device toolbar"

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

Here is the source code(CodePen) :  [Link to source code(codepen), you need to open files from a Folder to see the chrome console issue !](https://codepen.io/Ziratsu/pen/PXmJgZ)

I've built a WebSite with simple HTML/CSS and JavaScript, with a little of Jquery, ScrollMagic and GreenSock.

Then i've started working on the "responsiv" part of my site, opening the Chrome Console, cliking on "toggle device toolbar" and surprise, there a strange offset after the 1028px part.
And the more you go down (768px, 425px...) the biggest is the offset!
Here are the pics :

[offset at 320px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxdYy.png)

[offset at 624px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFnD.png)

I've already tried to remove all js librairies, but it changes nothing or the offset is a just a little bit tinier.

A few hours ago, I had the "violation" of non passiv event listener "mousewheel" issue, so i've tried to add this in my Js file:

`window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function () { }, { passive: true });`

But it was not effectiv. Now I have 0 errors on the console but still my huge offset problem on >1000px devices.

I hope someone can give me a hand, and sorry for my english, it's not my nativ language, don't hesitate to ask me more information about my issue!

Have a nice day/night!

Comment: I've published it on GitHub so you don't have to create a folder yourself,
https://ziratsu.github.io/ScrollSite/ just hit the "togle device toolbar" and go under 1000px !

Comment: I need a Hero ..